# No Datalab repository created when using Datalab init script to create Dataproc cluster

Tags: git, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I am creating a Dataproc cluster that uses Datalab. To initialize Datalab on the Dataproc cluster, I am creating the cluster from the cloud console and pointing to the [datalab.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/datalab/datalab.sh) initialization script from Google's [dataproc-initialization-actions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions) Github repository in the list of initialization scripts. However, when I do this, no Cloud Source Repository is created to version-control the notebooks. I am able to successfully connect to the VM instance and open Datalab, but when I create a new notebook (in the `notebooks/` folder), enter some commands, and click Notebook > Save and Checkpoint, nothing happens. When I click the icon to open ungit, ungit says "Nothing to commit" and "No remotes specified":

[image: empty ungit repository]

**Is this expected behavior for the Datalab initialization script I am using?**

Additional information: The [Datalab documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/working-with-notebooks) states that running `datalab create VM-instance-name` should create a `datalabs-notebook` Cloud Source Repository. I ran this command for a cluster that was created and then later destroyed, so when I open Cloud Source Repository in the console, I do see a `datalabs-notebook` source repository. However, when I open that repository from the cloud console, I do not see any notebooks in it.

If I SSH into the VM, and get a shell inside the Docker container running Datalab, I see that a git repository has been created, but there are no remotes:

```
/content> cd datalab/notebooks
/content/datalab/notebooks> ls
/content/datalab/notebooks> git status .
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
/content/datalab/notebooks> git remote -v
/content/datalab/notebooks>
```

(Note, this does not match the contents of the `datalab-notebook` repository as seen through the Cloud Source Repository - that has a `README.md` fille that just has the contents `# Project Notebooks`.)

**Do I need to add a `datalab create VM-instance-name` command to the [datalab_init.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/datalab/datalab.sh) script to create a git repository inside the Datalab container?** The Data Engineering training videos I am going through imply this should happen by default.

**EDIT/UPDATE 1:** To see if this was an issue specific to Dataproc (spoiler: it is), I tried creating a Datalab instance from a Cloud Shell using `datalab create my-new-vm`. This created a virtual machine running a Datalab instance, and I was able to connect via the browser to this instance. A git repository was correctly created in the `notebooks` directory, and things generally behaved as I would have expected. This indicates the issue of a Datalab notebooks git repository not initializing specific to the case of the `datalab.sh` initialization script being run on a Dataproc cluster.

**EDIT/UPDATE 2:** I tried using ungit to manually create a new git repository in `/content/datalabs/notebooks`, and then adding the git remote URL for the existing `datalab-notebooks` repository in Cloud Repository. However, when I do this, ungit requires me to authenticate with the remote repository (enter my username/password). My connection to the ungit page is unsecured HTTP, not HTTPS, and changing the URL to HTTPS results in a "Secure Connection Failed" error. So, I'm not able to test whether I can add the existing `datalab-notebooks` repository manually (since I am unwilling to send my Google Cloud username/password over an HTTP connection).

**EDIT/UPDATE 3:** I tried adding the command `CLUSTERNAME=/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value name; datalab create ${CLUSTERNAME}` to the Dataproc Datalab init script `datalab.sh` before the dataproc cluster starts up, but this results in `datalab: command not found`. Not sure why the complete Google Cloud SDK is unavailable on the Dataproc cluster, but that's another question... Meanwhile, the Dataproc team is looking into the diagnostic tarball I sent over.

**EDIT/UPDATE 4:** Google's Dataproc and Datalab teams have kindly offered to help out and take a look at the issue, so will update this question with any resolution or additional information from them.

Comment: If you experience this problem consistently, can you run `gcloud dataproc clusters diagnose <cluster-name>` and send the resulting tarball to dataproc-feedback@google.com?  Please also include the command you are using to initialize the cluster.  Adding `datalab create <VM-instance-name>` to the initialization action should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am able to reproduce this issue, so I will send in the diagnostics results.

Comment: @charlesreid1 Have you tried adding the `datalab create ...` command to the script? You can change `datalab.sh` and put it in your own GCS bucket to try it out any changes. (And feel free to send a PR if that fixes it!). @Axel you should consider reaching out to the datalab team to answer this question -- it doesn't seem like a dataproc issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Karthik. The issue actually is specific to Dataproc - if I create a Datalab instance from the Cloud Shell using `datalab create my-new-vm`, things work as expected. A git repository for notebooks is initialized in the `notebooks/` directory, and when I create a notebook in the `notebooks/` directory the changes appear in ungit.

Comment: It turns out `datalab` doesn't come with `gcloud` by default. [Instructions for downloading other gcloud components](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/managing-components). If you're installing datalab in the docker script, add `gcloud components install -q datalab`. If you're doing it on the GCE VM (outside of docker), use `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-datalab`.

Comment: @charlesreid1 were you able to resolve your issue? If so it is recommended to post the solution as an answer here to better help the community.

Comment: No, please see edit/update 4 in the post - it sounded like it might be a conflict between Datalab and Dataproc, so I reached out to the Google Cloud team and they're now dealing with the issue. I'll certainly update the thread once I know more.

Comment: It's four months later. I never heard back from Google support. Our organization is using Jupyter notebooks on AWS now so whatever.